# C invalid operands to binary

Tags: c

```
bool loadData(char *filename, int*id, double *amt, char*desig, int Size)
```

Having trouble with this function it is a `bool loadData` function, it gives this error when I try to compile:

```
invalid operands to binary * (have âintâ and âdouble *â)
     fscanf(filePointer, "%d %lf %c", (*id *amt *desig));
                                           ^
```

Comment: Use `fscanf(filePointer, "%d %lf %c", id, amt, desig)`. i.e; Seperate arguments by a comma not like what you did. And removed `*` as `fscanf` expects pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters to `scanf` need to be separated with commas.  The way you have it now, it looks like you're trying to multiply. Also, get rid of the extra parenthesis.

```
fscanf(filePointer, "%d %lf %c", id, amt, desig);
```